# AsciiDoc as a Markdown alternative on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, markdown

The idea came when I was at my [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) site: I realized it allows a bunch of these simple markup languages to be chosen from, including [AsciiDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AsciiDoc).

Is this purely impractical, and way too much overhead? Or an alternative to be considered?

Comment: Downvotes on Meta are slightly different from on the main sites; down-votes often indicate 'disagree with suggestion in question' rather than 'it is a badly written question' or ...

Comment: Since this change would obviously have lots of downsides (user interface complication, development time, maintenance increase, API complication, documentation complication, etc.) you should let us know why you think what you're requesting would be benefitial. The title doesn't tell that story.

Comment: But why? What's not enough or not correct now? What would you improve with this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I disapprove; I think standardizing on one format is important. If there were multiple markup languages, it would make it harder to edit other people's posts; the ability to jump in and improve existing content easily is a big part of what SE is about.

Comment: Err, it was the only answer that was given *at all*, @sjas. I'm not sure what you meant to say by that comment.

Comment: "horribly high horse" - maybe he's just _terribly short..._  I should state that after recent extensive research into all _markup_ formats for the purpose of writing full novels, I've decided AsciiDoc to be the most powerful (like MarkDown; but seriously upgraded).  However it pains me to agree that changing SE to AsciiDoc will confuse the masses...  (Maybe one day...)